# How To inject $http in Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) used in angular.constants()?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, I want to use `$http` service in `angular.constants()` using Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) some what like this.

**Example:**

```
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

        app.constant('STATIC',(function ($http) {
        $http.get('text.properties').then(function(result){
          console.log("In Constant "+ result);
          return result;
        });
      })());
```

but doing this give rise to an error saying `cannot read property get of undifined`

Point 1 of [This](https://vasya10.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/angularjs-startup-time-environment-configuration/) post says we cannot use `$http` as a dependency Injection to a constant. And as per [This](http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2012/12/23/angular-better-constant-values/), we can use IIFE to assign value then why can't we use `$http` as a DI to the same function.

Comment: @Claies. services can be injected in .run block, it is mainly there for that purpose.

Comment: @Claies. OH! when i tried debugging the code i saw the same i.e. my services were evaluated after the constant function. so is there any other way by which i can assign values to a constant by reading them from a file? and Thank you for the Help, appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers.  Constants cannot have dependencies.

Comment: @PranavGhate, have it as a service. where u can inject $http.

Comment: @Muthukannan. I have achieved the the same using service. i.e. reading values from a property file using $http DI in a service, but i wanted to achieve it using constants so i do not have to call the service again and again in rest of my code when ever i need the value from property file.

Comment: Please check my answer, service is like a singleton only. http call wont be made again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `$http` into `.run`

```
.run(function($http){
    //do http request, save it into a servce
})
```

Comment: it was a mistype, I already corrected the comment.  I'm not sure that this was something that should have been posted as an answer....

Comment: Ah, I see you corrected it. I have removed the reference to your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

app.service function will be executed only once, when angular is bootstrapped.
So it would make only one $http.get call and populate static variable with constants.

```
app.service('STATIC', function($http) {
    var static = this;

    $http.get('text.properties')
        .then(function(result) {
            result = result.data;

            static.CONSTANT_NAME_1 = result.value1;
            static.CONSTANT_NAME_2 = result.value2;
            static.CONSTANT_NAME_3 = result.value3;
            static.CONSTANT_NAME_4 = result.value4;
            static.CONSTANT_NAME_5 = result.value5;
        });
});
```

You can do this, and where you inject this you can access it like,

```
app.controller('SomeController1', function(STATIC, $log) {
    $log.debug(STATIC.CONSTANT_NAME_1);
});

app.controller('SomeController2', function(STATIC, $log) {
    $log.debug(STATIC.CONSTANT_NAME_2);
});
```

Comment: what if i have 10 values in the test.properties file and i have 10 controllers using 1 of the values then to get that value i will have to call the service 10 times right? just curious to know how the call is made!!